# What is the best way to attach properties to mongoose documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an array of posts and each post contains an author id. I want to loop through each post and find author from User model by using author id and then attach it to post. What is the best and efficient way to do it. I am currently doing it this way, but it decreases the performance. Thanks.

```
  posts = await Promise.all(
    posts.map(async post => {
      post.author = await User.findById(post.author).lean();
      return post;
    })
  );


  // POST SCHEMA

  const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   author: {
     type: String,
     required: true
   },
   body: {
     type: String,
     required: true
   },
   post_image: {
     url: String,
     public_id: String,
     width: Number,
     height: Number
   },
  date_created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
 });


 // USER SCHEMA


 const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
   type: String,
   required: true
  },
  email: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
   unique: true
  },
  password: {
   type: String,
   required: true
  },
  register_date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now()
  },
  friends: {
    type: Array,
    default: []
  }
 });
```

Comment: @chridam added post and user schema designs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  // NEW POST SCHEMA

  const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   author: {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: 'users',
     required: true
   },
   body: {
     type: String,
     required: true
   },
   post_image: {
     url: String,
     public_id: String,
     width: Number,
     height: Number
   },
  date_created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
 });


 // USER SCHEMA


 const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
   type: String,
   required: true
  },
  email: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
   unique: true
  },
  password: {
   type: String,
   required: true
  },
  register_date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now()
  },
  friends: [{
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: 'users',
     required: true
  }],
 });
```

You can use auto population of mongo object in mongoose. It won't cause performance issues as it uses id index. Similar to this doc: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Your query will look like this:

```
const post = await Post.find({ author: { $in: req.user.friends }})
                       .populate('author')
                       .exec();
console.log(post);
```

Or you can use aggregate according to this document: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html

Your query will then look like:

```
const query = [
      { $match: { author: { $in: req.user.friends } } },
      { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "author", foreignField: "_id", as: "authorDetails" } },
      { $unwind: "authorDetails" },
]
const post = await Post.aggregate(query).exec();
console.log(post);
```

Comment: I didn't test this. Let me know if you are facing any issues.

Comment: you are using date_created to fiilter documents, but i want to use author
Post.find({ author: { $in: req.user.friends }})

Comment: req.user.friends is an array i want to find all post in which author is inside req.user.friends array

Comment: You can change the criteria according to your need